# Can you join two oModels in a single list in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

Hi I am trying to show a single list that fetches data from two different oModels.

```
var Countries = {
    "countries":[
        {
            'country' : "AUS",
            'country_name' : "Australia"
        },
        {
            'country' : "USA",
            'country_name' : "United States of America"
        },
    ]
};

var CountriesStatus = {
    "countries":[
        {
            'country':"AUS",
            'status':"inactive"
        },
        {
            'country':"USA",
            'status':"active"
        }
    ]
};
```

Is it possible to load a single list where the title is `Countries>country_name` and description is `CountriesStatus>status`

Comment: Merge two Model data into a single object and create a new Model.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible. The [ListBinding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONListBinding) accepts only one model. This means, if you want to bind an aggregation, you would have to join the data into a single model and bind that one.